# Why does my play command keep giving me an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to make music playing command for my discord.js bot, but the file keeps giving me an error, and I don't understand why it does.

```js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const ytSearch = require("yt-search");

module.export = {
  name: "play",
  description: "Joins the vc and plays a yt vid",
  execute(message, args) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;

    if (!voiceChannel)
      return message.channel.send("You need to be in a vc to use this command");
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has("CONNECT"))
      return message.channel.send("You dont have the required permissions");
    if (!permissions.has("SPEAK"))
      return message.channel.send("You dont have the required permissions");
    if (!args.length)
      return message.channel.send("You need to send the second argument");

    const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
      const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

      return videoResult.videos.length > 1 ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
    };

    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(" "));

    if (video) {
      const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: "audioonly" });
      connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 });
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add details regarding the error you are receiving. Also, you had a lot of syntax errors in the snippet you provided. Please compare your source with the edited version to see if you made some mistakes.

Comment: What is the error? Did I have to guess what it is

Comment: error: https://sourceb.in/DfvrNMpHZG

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[given error](https://sourceb.in/DfvrNMpHZG)** you were having a typo with your code which lead to the given syntax error,
it is

```
 + module.exports 
 - module.export // not this
```

Made appropriate changes [here](https://sourceb.in/eLQ5P2P91y)